# Python Jinja Variables Don't Add

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a project in flask and am trying a trick to run two foreach loops. I'm doing this by creating a variable and adding 1 to it after each loop like so:

```
{% set iteration = 0 %}

    {% for result in results %}
      <p id="{{ results_raw[iteration] }}">{{ result }}</p> <br>
      {% set iteration = iteration + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

The iteration variable should go from 0 to 1 to 2 and so on. "results_raw" is a dictionary with 6 strings. When this code runs, the 0th string keeps printing over and over, meaning that the iterations variable is not increasing. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Is results_raw = {0 : "string", 1 : "another string] ..}

Comment: No, results_raw looks something like, {"blah", "blahblah", "blahblahblah"...}

Comment: Would {{loop.index0}} suffice what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the iteration variable, you could access loop.index and loop.index0 inside a for loop

Refer to this documentation: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/

> loop.index , The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)

> loop.index0, The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

```html
{% for result in results %}
      <p id="{{ results_raw[loop.index0] }}">{{ result }}</p> <br>
      
{% endfor %}
```